# Best approach or algorithm to solve equation with multiple variables?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, problem-solving

I have an equation :

$A^6x_1 + A^5x_2 + A^4x_3 + A^3x_4 + A^2x_5 + A^1x_6 + x_7 = B$

What can be the best algorithm/approach I can use to crack this?

$A$ and $B$ are constants. $x_1,x_2...x_7$ are variables. 
A is a prime number.
Sorry for not stating this earlier variables can have values from 0 to 15.
The algorithm should be efficient.

Comment: Any constraints on $x_1,\dots,x_7$? Otherwise just $x_1 = B/A^6$ and $x_2=\dots=x_7=0$ is a trivial solution.

Comment: You want all solutions, or just one?

Comment: You can give arbitrary values for all the variables but one (say $x_1$) then you solve for $x_1$.

Comment: Sorry for not stating this earlier the constraints are :variables can have values from 0 to 15. The algorithm should be efficient.

Comment: Is this Diophantine? (ie. integer solutions only)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_7$ be the remainder when $B$ is divided by $A$. Let $B_1 = (B-x_7)/A$.

Let $x_6$ be the remainder when $B_1$ is divided by $A$. Let $B_2 = (B_1-x_6)/A$.

Let $x_5$ be the remainder when $B_2$ is divided by $A$. Let $B_3 = (B_2-x_5)/A$.

...

Let $x_2$ be the remainder when $B_5$ is divided by $A$. Let $B_6 = (B_5-x_2)/A$.

Finally, let $x_1 = B_6/A$.

This is basically the algorithm to write an integer $B$ in base-$A$, except you stop after getting $7$ digits.